# Why is $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] empty in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made the GET request:

```
mysite.com/api/v1/articles?category=news
```

Then checked the $_SERVER on Wordpress:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '\/wp-json\/api\/v1\/articles?category=news'
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == ''
```

Why were the query arguments empty? $_GET was also empty.